# Strings Expansion is changing order or the string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to so some normal variable expansion in a string and, when it's in a function, it comes out out-of-order.

```
function MakeMessage99($startValue, $endValue) { "Ranges from $startValue to $endValue" }

MakeMessage99(1, 100)
```

This returns `Ranges from 1 100 to` then it should return `Ranges from 1 to 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in powershell shouldn't use parenthesis to enclose parameters.  Instead:

```
PS C:\> MakeMessage99 1 100
Ranges from 1 to 100
```

Where MakeMessage is your function, "1" is a parameter in the first position, and "100" is a parameter in the second position.  According to [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx):

> By default, all function parameters are positional. Windows PowerShell assigns position numbers to parameters in the order in which the parameters are declared in the function.

Powershell has several ways to check input going in. You could cast the input as a numeric type. There are also baked-in validation methods for parameters that may prevent this sort of error in the future.  If you really want an integer, a simple cast would cause an array to be invalid input.  For example:

```
function MakeMessage99 {
  Param
  (
    [int]$startValue, 
    [int]$endValue
  ) 

  "Ranges from $startValue to $endValue" 
}
```

You could also explore range validation (such as `[ValidateRange(0,100)]`), pattern validation (such as `[ValidatePattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")]` to validate a four-digit number) or other validation attributes listed in the link above.

Comment: Argh. Powershell keeps making my feel stupid. I get that confused with the syntax for calling framework methods (which seem to like parentheses). Nice descriptive answer, btw.

Comment: No worries.  Take a look through the questions in the [powershell tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell?sort=votes&pageSize=50) here with accepted answers. Very many of the powershell questions asked have small, easy-to-replicate examples that would be good to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pitfall in PowerShell.  When you invoke...

```
MakeMessage99(1, 100)
```

...you're actually passing an array containing the values `1` and `100` as the first parameter.  To pass `1` as the first parameter and `100` as the second parameter, use...

```
MakeMessage99 1 100
```